# How to make popup modal appear when clicking a link using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I have few links that when user click on the link, it will appear as popup modal. However, what I have done was there modal appear but without content. I am new to ajax so I quite not understand what should I do.
Below is my HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="answerModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">ANSWER</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href=#link1 data-target="#answerModal"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href=#link2 data-target="#answerModal"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href=#link3 data-target="#answerModal"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
```

Below is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).data('url');
  console.log(ok);
  // AJAX request
  $.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: 'get',
    data: link,
    success: function(response){ 
    // Add response in Modal body
      $('.modal-body').html(response);
    // Display Modal
    $('#answerModal').modal('show'); 
    }
  });
});});});
```

[This is how my modal looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78i4W.png)

Comment: can not understand what is your issue and what is your expectation can you please clarify it?

Comment: @maulikbafalipara when I click the link, it supposed to display a page in the popup modal. Is that make sense? For now, my popup modal not display the link that I clicked.

Comment: please provide valid data there is an error In your script,  and missing data value in HTML.

Comment: @maulikbafalipara im sorry. can you tell me where is the error in the script because im not really understand how it works that is why im having this problem.

Comment: i added an answer please check it and let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the changes and checks that are needed to be done.

1. remove `data-toggle` and `data-target` from your `<a>` tags, as they ends up opening the modal regardless of api call is successful or not. And in case of API failure there is not content to show in modal.
2. add a console.log in your success function of api call just to confirm that the api call successful or not.
3. Make sure that the `var link = $(this).data("url");` is not undefined.

I am also adding a working snippet just for your reference using placeholder api calls, replace them with your actual url you want to hit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="answerModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">ANSWER</h4>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                        >
                            &times;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                        >
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/5"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
        <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/6"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
        <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/7"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".btn").click(function () {
                    var link = $(this).data("url");
                    console.log(link);
                    if(!link || (link === '')){
                        $(".modal-body").html("<p>Invalid link!</p>");
                        $("#answerModal").modal("show");
                        return;
                    }
                    // AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                        url: link,
                        type: "get",
                        data: link,
                        success: function (response) {
                            // Add response in Modal body
                            console.log(response)
                            console.log("api successful");
                            $(".modal-body").html(JSON.stringify(response));
                            // Display Modal
                            $("#answerModal").modal("show");
                        },
                        error: function(err){
                            $(".modal-body").html(err.responseText);
                            $("#answerModal").modal("show");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it seems does not working since the url is different for every `<a>`. For example `<a href="www.google.com"></a>`, `<a href="www.yahoo.com"></a>`. So the `url:` in the `<script>` is based on the link clicked. But must appear as a modal. Is that make sense?

Comment: check now, i have updated the solution to hit links specified in a tags url data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had some changes to your code please check it below.
Also added if API did not respond success or link is blank then error modal show.

you added one extra closing bracket at end of your js "});".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="answerModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">ANSWER</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times; </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"></div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
    <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
    <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url=""> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
    <a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)" data-url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/abcd"> VIEW ANSWER → </a>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btn").click(function() {
          var link = $(this).data("url");
          console.log(link);
          // AJAX request
          if (link == undefined || link == '') {
            $(".modal-body").html("<p>if link is not available then Your error message display here!!!</p>");
            $("#answerModal").modal("show");
          } else {
            $.ajax({
              url: link,
              type: "get",
              data: link,
              success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                console.log("api successful");
                $(".modal-body").html(JSON.stringify(response));
                $("#answerModal").modal("show");
              },
              error: function(response) {
                $(".modal-body").html("<p>Please try after some time...</p>");
                $("#answerModal").modal("show");
              },
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/), which manages the modal popup for you. You then could implement the link as:

```html
<a href="YOUR LINK" onclick="popup()">This is a link!</a>
```

This is some starter JavaScript code (you can add your own stuff):

```js
function popup(){
    Swal.fire(){
        title: "Hey you clicked the link!"
    }
}
```

To get the most out of Sweet Alert 2, you can access the documentation and some examples at their [website](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)